Dealing with system-protected files
I need to create a list of files from the system drive, then perform an operation on each file in the list. I understand that some files in the system drive are system-protected, and that I do not have access to them.
So how can I have my code IGNORE those files and not write them to the list in the first place, so that I will not get "Resolve-Path" or "access is denied" errors when the file operation part begins?
I have tried to add -ErrorAction Ignore or -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue in various places in my script, but still haven't been able to suppress those errors.
Thanks!
This is what I want to avoid:

Shane
EDIT: code below
Clear-Host
$StartTime = $(get-date)
# Define the folder to be hashed
$folder = "C:\Program Files (x86)"
#create output folder if not already present
new-item -path "C:\temp\" -Name "Hashes" -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# Define the output file path
$outputPath = "C:\temp\Hashes\Hashfile.txt"

# Get all files in the folder and its subfolders
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -Like "*.dll" `
-or $_.Name -like "*.exe" -or $_.Name -like "*.com" -or $_.Name -like "*.cmd" -or $_.Name -like "*.bat"} 
#output file list to baseline list text file
$files | Select-Object FullName | format-table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String -Width 500 | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim("`r","`n") } | Out-File -Encoding ascii "C:\temp\Hashes\file_list.txt"
# Initialize the progress counter
$counter = 0
$total = $files.Count

# Initialize the output file
"File Path      Hash Value" | Out-File -Encoding ascii $outputPath

# Loop through each file and calculate its SHA256 hash
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $hash = Get-FileHash -Path $file.FullName -Algorithm SHA256
    $line = '' + $file.FullName + '      ' + $hash.Hash +''
    $line | Out-File -Encoding ascii $outputPath -Append
    $counter++
    
    # Update the progress meter
    $percent = [int]($counter / $total * 100)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Calculating Hashes" -Status "Processing file $($file.FullName)" -PercentComplete $percent
}

# Remove the progress meter
Write-Progress -Activity "Calculating Hashes" -Completed

# Display a message when the script is finished
Write-Host "Hashes calculated for $($total) files in $($folder). Results saved to $($outputPath)."
$elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $StartTime
$totalTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$elapsedTime.Ticks)
Write-Host "`Took $totalTime to execute."


Can you please add the code you currently have? Have you tried adding error handling with try / catch blocks?

I added the code and a screenshot to my original post to help explain my dilemma. And no, I have not tried try/catch - not really sure how to use that here, if I am being honest.

And what do you want to happen when there is an inaccessible file? If its suppressing errors then adding Get-FileHash -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ... should do that

What I would really like is for files that are inaccessible to not be hashed, but listed anyway. If that is not feasible, then I would have the files not appear in the list at all, and therefore hashing not even see them. I will try adding that statement to my code. Thank you for helping!

Well that worked! I feel like an idiot - I though for sure I had tried putting the -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue there before. Thank you!!

I recommend you to export your data to CSV so you can easily read it back. The approach you can take with a try / catch block goes like this:
$files | ForEach-Object {
    $reason = $hash = $null

    try {
        $hash = Get-FileHash -Path $file.FullName -Algorithm SHA256 -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        $reason = $_.Exception.Message
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        'File Path'  = $_.FullName
        'Hash Value' = $hash.Hash # When hashing failed this value will be empty
        'Error'      = $reason    # and this value will have the reason why it failed
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\temp\Hashes\Hashfile.csv -NoTypeInformation

